# New String Object Creation - Allocate memory in Normal Memory and String Constant Pool? Both?

Tags: string, memory-management, jvm

```
String s = new String("abc");
```

When we use the new keyword, Java will create a new String object in normal(nonpool) memory and s will refer to it. In addition, the literal "abc" will be placed in the pool.

I found this information in certification book. I am curious about this, JVM is adding "abc" in String Constant Pool after adding "abc" in normal memory, then why is it creating "abc" in normal memory? Whereas, It can directly allocate space in String Constant Pool?

Some reasons behind that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a “normal memory” and “pool memory”.

All `String` instances live on the heap, which is, by definition, the memory holding all Java objects. There is a string pool, which is basically a kind of hash map, containing *references* to instances. There is no requirement for the `String` instance to be in a special memory region, to be referable by the string pool. Adding a string to the pool does not imply any memory movement.

In older JVMs, the instances created for string *literals* were placed into a special memory region, to accommodate the lower likelihood of being garbage collected. Since that memory region, called *permanent generation* had some drawbacks, this policy was abandoned and the memory region removed in Java 8. This old behavior might have created some confusion. But it never was a requirement for strings referred by the pool, to be in that memory region.

Besides that, it’s not clear where your question is aiming at. You have written code requesting Java to create two distinct `String` instances and Java will do so. The reason why it does so, is, because you told it so.

If you really want to go deeper into the technical details, this is, what will happen with your code:

- First, an uninitialized `String` instance is created for your `new String(…)` request
- Then, a `String` instance for your `"abc"` literal is created and added to the pool (unless the pool does already contain a string of that content)
- Last, the constructor for the `String` instance created by the first step is invoked, with the `String` instance of the second step as argument

  - within the constructor, the *reference* to the `char[]` array will be copied

At the end, you have two instances with the same contents, as you requested, both pointing to the same array (since Java 7u6), so the single array obviously can’t be in different memory regions for the two strings.